# Why jQuery prepend is not working on server and working fine on localhost?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prepend

What i am trying to do is when user click on user on list then that `li` should be move to the top.

here is my code.

```
$(document).on('click', '.list_user_id', function(){

        var old_user_list ;

        var recipient_idd = $(this).data('list_user_id');


        $('ul.user_list > li.active').removeClass('active');        
        $('ul.user_list > li').css('display','block');        

        old_user_list = $('ul.user_list').html();
        $('#recipient_idd').val(recipient_idd);
        $('.message_box_footer').show(100);

        $.ajax({
          url: "<?php echo base_url('messages/get_single_user_messages/')?>"+$(this).data('list_user_id'),
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "html",
          success: function(data){
            $('.direct-chat-messages').html(data);
            $('#direct-chat-messages').animate({scrollTop: $('#direct-chat-messages').prop("scrollHeight")}, 500);

            $('ul.user_list').html(old_user_list);

            // this line is not working on server. 
            $($('#list_user_id_'+recipient_idd)).parent().prepend($('#list_user_id_'+recipient_idd));


            $('ul.user_list').find('#list_user_id_'+recipient_idd).addClass('active');


          }    
        });  
    });
```

in above code, everything seems working fine but below line is NOT working on server.

```
$($('#list_user_id_'+recipient_idd)).parent().prepend($('#list_user_id_'+recipient_idd));
```

I have already tried with set interval but not working.

here is non working demo on server : https://nimb.ws/k9bfHU

here is working demo on localhost : https://nimb.ws/YcSemw

Comment: Are there any error messages in your browser console? Is your server running PHP in order to parse that `<?php echo base_url('messages/get_single_user_messages/')?>` line?

Comment: No. Everything seems fine.